# How to properly use a time series using pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am attempting to create a time series index using pandas. Currently this is the code I am running:

```
date_string = df3["Date"]  
date_times = pd.to_datetime(date_string, yearfirst=True, format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
df3_i  = df3.set_index(date_times)
```

Yet I am getting constant errors. Can anyone explain?
Error:

```
ValueError: time data '2017-03-08 13:53' does not match format '%Y%m%d%H:%M' (match)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the format is `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`

There are special character combinations that are meant to represent the numeric components of the date and time.  A great reference can be found [***here***](http://www.strftime.org)

You have a time string of `'2017-03-08 13:53'` as evidenced by you error message.  From the link you'll find that:

- 4 digit year is `'%Y'`
- 2 digit month is `'%m'`
- 2 digit day is `'%d'`
- 2 digit hour is `'%H'`
- 2 digit minute is `'%M'`

So you still need to represent the other string bits like the dashes, space, and the colon

Thus `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`

Use this instead

```
date_string = df3["Date"]  
date_times = pd.to_datetime(date_string, yearfirst=True, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df3_i  = df3.set_index(date_times)
```

If that doesn't work, then you have inconsistent date formats and my first course of action would be to yell at whoever created the thing I'm trying to parse.

If that happens to be your scenario, ask another question... Or I might.

Comment: I recommend using `infer_datetime_format = True` and bypass any statically coded format altogether... unless you're 100% sure of the format.  It also usually speeds up parsing.

Comment: That didn't work. And, I already looked at the source for answers yet I am still getting an error. I think the some of the dates do not have leading zeros.